# what does {1} mean in |master {1} ✓| with bashit?

Tags: bash, git, bash-it

I have a git bash shell extension defined it shows `|master {1} ✓|` what does the `{1}` mean?

```
|master {1} ✓| → git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What does the `{1}` mean in the prompt? I am using bash configured with https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the [base theme](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/721412aa4ca56cde3dd11efc3bdfc85c1368dba7/themes/base.theme.bash#L38) it means you have one stashed set of changes.

See `git stash list`.